# Looking for recommendations to migrate data into an Entity Framework Code First generated Database

Tags: entity-framework, data-migration

I'm trying to figure out how to migrate data from an SQL server database to an entity framework database that's generated with code first.

The source database doesn't match the schema exactly so I have some code that will do the migration. What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to move the data over and preserve the IDs.
I have zero attributes applied to my model. I'm just using the modelnameID convention for the primary key property.

Should I turn off identity generation, migrate data, then turn it back on? What happens to the next value?
Should I turn off identity permanently and manage the IDs myself?
Any other suggestions?

Edit: I'm using SQL CE 4 for my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code to do it. You won't be able to use DBCC, but you can just alter your column:

```
var connection = new SqlCeConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
new SqlCeCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Songs] ON;", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO table values", connection);
new SqlCeCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Songs] OFF;", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();

new SqlCeCommand("ALTER TABLE Songs ALTER COLUMN SongID IDENTITY(100,1)", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off identity generation.

Transfer data.

Turn identity generation back on.

Use reseed to set the value of the next id, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Comment: I'm also using SQL CE 4, does the command also work for SQLCE4?